# HttpRequestBase in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

```
var redirectUrl = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext).Action(urlActionContext);
```

`Request` class this code is throwing the following error - I am creating an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web app:

[image]

I tried importing `System.Web` but still of no use.

Comment: Could you please share your exact `code snippet` instead of screenshot?

Comment: `Namespsce` also added you might not noticed, these are the `namesapece` sing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;`